# 'dict' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, odoo

I have python code (odoo)

```
    @api.one
def mps_value(self,cr):
    fc = self.forecast_id
    cr.execute("""SELECT SUM(sol.product_uom_qty) 
                FROM sale_order_line AS sol , sale_order AS s , forecastmps_forecast AS fc , forecastmps_period AS pd 
                WHERE fc.id = %s AND sol.product_id = fc.product_id AND fc.period_id = pd.id AND pd.start_date <= sol.create_date 
                AND sol.create_date <= pd.end_date AND s.state = \'done\' AND sol.order_id = s.id""", (fc,))
    ret = cr.fetchone()[0]
    return ret
```

I run it and this is error

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

How can i fix it . Thank you .

Comment: How do you call mps_value()? Apparently you're giving it a dictionary whereas it expects some sort of database connection handler.

Comment: cr needs to be a cursor, you seem to be passing a dict.

Comment: I call i method button:
<button type= "object" name ="mps_value" string ="Load database"></button>

Comment: @over09030, there is a little link "edit" under your post, where you can edit your post and add updates (I rejected the edit you tried to do on Alessandro answer, edit your post instead)

Answer (score 2):

You should try following,

Remove cr (cursor) from method definition and do not pass any parameter while you calling this function.

```
@api.one
def mps_value(self):
    fc = self.forecast_id.id
    self.env.cr.execute("""SELECT SUM(sol.product_uom_qty) 
                FROM sale_order_line AS sol , sale_order AS s , forecastmps_forecast AS fc , forecastmps_period AS pd 
                WHERE fc.id = %s AND sol.product_id = fc.product_id AND fc.period_id = pd.id AND pd.start_date <= sol.create_date 
                AND sol.create_date <= pd.end_date AND s.state = \'done\' AND sol.order_id = s.id""", (fc,))
    ret = self.env.cr.fetchone()[0]
    return ret
```

Comment: Given the error underneath, I'll say it is **fc.id** as parameter of the query

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing v7 and v8.
Remove the cr parameter and use the ORM methods in order to calculate that sum.
Besides, the value you return is "lost" i.e. not used anywhere...

Answer (score 1):

To execute the query try following:

```
self.env.cr.execute(<your query>)
```

OR

```
self._cr.execute(<your query>)
```

You don't need `cr` in your function argument in new api.

Comment: @over09030 if you want to stick by using cursor, use this solution. Still, remove the **cr** parameter.

Comment: `@api.one
    def mps_value(self):
        self.env.cr.execute("""SELECT SUM(sol.product_uom_qty)
                    FROM sale_order_line AS sol , sale_order AS s , forecastmps_forecast AS fc , forecastmps_period AS pd 
                    WHERE fc.id = %s AND sol.product_id = fc.product_id AND fc.period_id = pd.id AND pd.start_date <= sol.create_date AND sol.create_date <= pd.end_date AND s.state = 'done' AND sol.order_id = s.id""",(self.forecast_id,))
        ret = cr.fetchone()[0]`
        return ret` i This is new error `ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'forecastmps.forecast'`